# Inserting an array into table MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have an array as follows:

```
call array_create('test', 5);
set @list = 'trying:something:out:for:first';
call array_from_list_complete(@list, 'testarray', ':');
```

How can I create a field in table using `create table ...` to store the array, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id_ int(5),
    number INT(10),
    *array, 
    PRIMARY KEY (int),
    )
```

Also, how can I insert that array into the table:

```
INSERT INTO test (id_, number, array) VALUES('data1', 'data2', 'testarray');
```

Comment: There should only ever be one value per cell, as per the rules of normalisation. Perhaps it might be worth creating an intermediate table and inserting each value?

Comment: Maybe a table in table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the array and store in DB(array to json).
While fetching you need to unserialize(json to array)